# JSON data from API to a backbone model

Tags: api, backbone.js

I am new to this site and new to Backbone.js

I am wondering if there is a way to save JSON data to a Backbone model.

I am getting data from an API whenever I search through it, and what I would like to do is when I click on "Add" on a result, it adds to the users favorites.

Could someone explain how it should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Backbone Models and Collections are designed to work with a RESTful API. After you create a Model and a new instance of it you can call the `fetch()` method to trigger a GET request to the REST API to get the model data. For example:

```
// We'll first create a User model and a Users collection
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: User});

// Now, to get a list of all users we can use the fetch() method on the users collection
var users = new Users();
users.fetch();

// Calling the fetch() method will trigger a GET request. By default Backbone will send the 
// request to '/users'. When the async call is done we'll end up with a collection filled
// with 'user' models.
```

I suggest that you read the [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) where it explains this and more. Also, if you want to know how this functions work you should can take a look at the [annotates source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html), which is great.